# Simple Contour map

Tags: r, contour, ggmap

I just discovered ggmap and I've been playing around with plotting earthquake data from the USGS.  I get the data in the form of Lat and Lon, depth and magnitude.  I can easily plot the earthquakes as points with different colors based on depth but what I would like to do is take that depth data (just a single number) and generate contours to overlay on the map.

This seems like it should be MUCH more simple than the "Houston Crime" example I keep coming  up on since I'm not doing any statistical "density" calculation or anything like that.  Basically it's just a contour map on top of the google map of an area.

How do I do this (Presumably) simple, simple thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem of plotting a 3D surface using only a small sample of unequally spaced lat/long points and a height z (or equivalent) variable is non-trivial -- you have to estimate the values of z for all of the lat-long grid coordinates you do not have, for example using loess() or kriging to create a smooth surface.

Take a look at [Methods for doing heatmaps, level / contour plots, and hexagonal binning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851602/methods-for-doing-heatmaps-level-contour-plots-and-hexagonal-binning), case #5. For a geoR example see http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~reich/CUSP/Ordinary_Kriging_in_R.pdf