# How to plot contours with a log scale in an interactive graph in R?

Tags: r, plotly

I have a contour plot displayed with plotly:

```
x <- rep(seq(0.01, 0.1, length.out = 50), 50)
y <- rep(seq(0.01, 0.1, length.out = 50), each = 50)
z <- 1 / (x^2 + y^2)

my.data <- data.frame(x, y, z)

p <- plot_ly(data = my.data, x = x, y = y, z = z, type = "contour")
```

Here is the result:

[image: No log scale]

**Question:** How to use a log scale for the z colors? Or how to manually control the contour levels?

I tried `layout(p, zaxis = list(type = "log"))` but it does not work.

**Remark #1:** I don't want to plot `log(z)`, which is the obvious solution, but to have a log color scale.

**Remark #2:** if it's not possible with plotly, what interactive graph library can do it? I need a library that exports my graph to an html file.

**Remark #3:** I tried plotting with ggplot in log scale and then using the ggplotly command, but in the end, plotly just plots log(z).

**Remark #4:** I tried with heat maps, manually setting the colour scale as indicated [here](https://plot.ly/r/heatmaps/), but could not make it work.

Comment: you could use ggplot2 and ggplotly()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the workaround I finally came up with:

```
ggplot(my.data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("blue",
                                   "cyan",
                                   "green",
                                   "yellow",
                                   "orange",
                                   "red"),
                       values = rescale(c(0.3, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 35))) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))

ggplotly()
```

So the idea was to manually set the color scale in `ggplot2` and then convert it with `ggplotly` command.

Here is the result:

[image: Better]

The only remaining problem is the color scale, which is not logarithmic. I can easily change the breaks, but I don't know how to change the colors. I guess this is the subject of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010031/how-to-modify-the-colors-in-the-legend-of-a-plot-using-a-fill-gradient)...

Another critic of this answer is that I don't have the discrete colors on the graph that I had with plotly, but rather a continuous gradient.

I tried using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570221/how-to-make-a-ggplot2-contour-plot-analogue-to-latticefilled-contour), but then the interactive graph does not indicate the exact value of z on mouse hover, but the range (e.g. "[0.3, 1)"), which is not helping and makes it lose the interest of the interactivity.

Alternate solutions are thus welcome!