# ggplot2 geom_contour how to remove the gray panel around a plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, contour

ggplot2 provides a useful buffer area around plots so that the data doesn't extend all the way up to the axis lines.  Usually this is helpful.  But it can be irritating, especially for contour plots or filled contour plots, where the plotted image is full of color and is (by default) surrounded by these gray boxes.

This example is taken from [How to make a ggplot2 contour plot analogue to lattice:filled.contour()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570221/how-to-make-a-ggplot2-contour-plot-analogue-to-latticefilled-contour), as is the answer below.  I'm posting it here as a question because I spent several hours hunting for it and expect others may have a similar need.

Example:

```
#contour plot using ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2) #for melt()
z.molten<-melt(z.lattice) 
names(z.molten) <- c("x", "y", "z")
v<-ggplot(z.molten, aes(x,y,z=z))+
    geom_tile(aes(fill=z))+
    stat_contour(bins=6,aes(x,y,z=z), color="black", size=0.6)+
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=brewer.pal(6,"YlOrRd"))
v
```

With result

[image: contour plot with irritating gray border]

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this, posted parenthetically by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2985007/jlhoward, is to use

```
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
```

in your ggplot2 code, i.e. as in the solution to the original problem:

```
x<-seq(1,11,.03)                    # note finer grid
y<-seq(1,11,.03)
xyz.func<-function(x,y) {-10.4+6.53*x+6.53*y-0.167*x^2-0.167*y^2+0.0500*x*y}
gg <- expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
gg$z <- with(gg,xyz.func(x,y))      # need long format for ggplot
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)               #for brewer.pal()
brks <- cut(gg$z,breaks=seq(0,100,len=6))
brks <- gsub(","," - ",brks,fixed=TRUE)
gg$brks <- gsub("\\(|\\]","",brks)  # reformat guide labels
ggplot(gg,aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=brks))+
  scale_fill_manual("Z",values=brewer.pal(6,"YlOrRd"))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  coord_fixed()
```

Resulting in:

[image: Contour plot without irritating gray border]

Many thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2985007/jlhoward!!