# Estimate data on point by using kriging (R)

Tags: r

I've got data of 38 locations and at many different timestamps. For all locations I've got the coordinates. Now I would like to estimate my data on a point which is not on one of these 38 locations. I would like to do this for all timestamps.

I found out that kriging is probably the best option to obtain these estimated values, but I've found many packages about it and many different ways to do this.

Now is my question, what is the best way to tackle my problem?

Comment: So is your question -> which method of Kriging is best in R?  Because I'm not sure SO is the best place to ask this question to be honest

Comment: Partially. The main question is which package to use to estimate the data in R. I don't need all those graph creating techniques, but only the formula's to estimate data on one place, given the data of the other places.

Comment: Look at my answer here for simple interpolation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006045/obtain-function-from-akimainterp-matrix/43064436#43064436
Otherwise, if you really want kriging, you can use librarie `gstat` or `geoR`